# Equivalent R "findcorrelation(corr,cutoff = 0.75)" in python pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have dataFrame named "data". I calculated correlation for data:

```
corr = data.corr()
```

I wanted remove columns which have correlation greater than 0.75 from "data" file.
This can be done in R very easily using the following command:

```
hc=findCorrelation(corr,cutoff = 0.75)
data <- data[,-c(hc)]
```

I am looking for similar command in python. Is there any command in pandas or scikit-learn which can do the similar job ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1. Prepare some data**

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

covs = np.eye(10)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if i!=j:
            covs[i,j] = (i*j)/100

mvn = multivariate_normal(cov=covs)
data = mvn.rvs(size = 100)
data.shape
(100, 10)
```

**Step 2. Vizualize correlation.**

Here, you have a 2-d correlated ndarray. The data is organized into columns, cases are in rows. In order to run correlation on column data, you need to transpose the array first (*hint: numpy runs correlation row-wise*):

```
r = np.corrcoef(data.T)
plt.imshow(r, cmap = "coolwarm")
plt.colorbar();
```

[image]

As you might see, some columns (*features*, as they say in Statistics or ML) are highly correlated.

**Step 3. Drop correlated columns**

Let's find which ones are correlated in excess of `.5` threshold, excluding diagonal elements, which are obviously perfectly self-correlated:

```
idx = np.abs(np.tril(r, k= -1)) < .5
idx_drop = np.all(idx, axis=1)
data_uncorr = data[:, idx_drop]
data_uncorr.shape
(100, 8)
```

which means we got rid off 2 collinear columns.

**Step 4. Sanity check**

Let's do some checking, visually and mathematically:

```
plt.imshow(np.corrcoef(data_uncorr.T), cmap = "coolwarm")
plt.colorbar();
```

[image]

```
np.sum(np.abs(np.tril(np.corrcoef(data_uncorr.T), k=-1)) >.5)
0
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent option in pandas as well @Sergey, One small question can we find column name/number from a file for which any value in the column is nonzero.

Comment: colNamesToDrop = df.columns[~idx_drop], more or less

Comment: Any command to find from any datframe, column for which value is non zero.

Comment: I am not getting you... What do you mean "column for which value is non zero"??? Column is a sequence of values as I understand it....

Comment: suppose I have a matrix with 5x10. Now for the column 2, all values are Zero for all 5 row, but for column 4 all values for every row is zero except for row 3  value is not zero. I wanted a command which prints the column number that for column 4 value is non-zero. Gives me output as column id in pandas

Comment: More or less df.sum() == 0 , but this question deserves starting a separate thread....

Comment: It solved the problem I approved it, though I am cross checking the values with R data